# How to update field by name?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of the following form:

```
id
id_ref
value1
value2
...
valueN
```

where value1->N are integer fields, and a function that receives an integer parameter "value" that specifies which field needs to be updated, i.e. if "value" param is 2, then only value2 field will be updated.

What I would like to do(in the function), is something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_cool_function(value integer) RETURNS bigint AS
...
UPDATE [table name here]
SET "value" || CAST(value[parameter] AS varchar) = [some value]
WHERE [condition];
...
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
...
```

but the above code is not correct, looking for a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't build identifiers like that but you can use [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to run some SQL that is in a string:

```
execute 'update table set '
     || quote_ident('value' || value)
     || ' = '
     || quote_literal('some value')
     || ' where ...';
```

You may or may not need the [`quote_ident` and `quote_literal`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) calls but I'd probably use them to help build good habits. You can avoid the `quote_literal` with USING:

```
execute 'update table set '
     || quote_ident('value' || value)
     || ' = $1'
     || ' where ...' using some_value;
```

Comment: +1 thank you @mu is to short (:, are you 100% sure that there's no other way besides EXECUTE? that's the only solution I could come up with also...

Comment: @DorinDuminica: I think EXECUTE is all you've got here but I could be wrong so give it some time. There's always a big ugly IF block with UPDATEs inside but that's pretty hideous too.

Comment: yeah, the IF's are not going to work... I'll give the question a bit more time, if no one else comes up with something "better", I'll accept yours, thank you!